# Rails 4 + Simple Form: Time Select will not remain blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a form:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4 time-input mb10">
            <%= f.input :wake_time, as: :time, minute_step: 15, ampm: true, include_blank: true , default: 'blank', label: "Wake Time" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-8 mb10">
            <%= f.input :wake_d, label: "Description", input_html: { class: 'form-input' }, include_blank: true  %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but despite having `include_blank: true` and `default: blank`, when I submit the form, the following SQL is generated:

```
SQL (9.8ms)  INSERT INTO "repositionings" ("wake_d", "wake_time") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["wake_d", ""], ["wake_time", "0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000"]]
```

even though both fields were left blank.  As you can see a generic time of `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000` is being inserted instead of `nil`.  **How can I get around this so that `nil` is accepted?**

Comment: `include_blank` is for select fields. For `f.input` you can use conditional values, like `value: wake_time || " "`. See [Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)